# What are the Metrics that Grafana can collect?

Tags: grafana

I am trying to know about GRAFANA advantages over other tools.Can anybody list what are all the metrics that GRAFANA Displays/Collects ? This helps a lot to starters.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Some of the metrics are:                                                                          system performance of virtual servers ,                                              CPU and Memory
HTTP,Disk space used 
time series data for infrastructure......please add some more type of metrics if u know

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be a little confused about what Grafana does.  It is a visualization tool, and is agnostic about the types of data you're visualizing.  That is what makes it much more powerful than tools that are more tightly integrated with a particular collector/database.

As long as you can get the data you want to visualize (and in 4.x alert on) into one of the many time-series databases that Grafana supports, you'll be able to visualize that data on Grafana dashboards.

If you want to get an idea of what time-series databases are supported, you can look at the docs for Graphite and the other built-in datasources http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/ (see the others in the side menu), and find more datasources supported via plugins on https://grafana.net/plugins